# Hash::make not working in laravel 5.0 Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I new on laravel 5.0 see error https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZMgZ.png
Here is my controller code

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
class DealerController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function login(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function index() {
        return view('login');

    }
    public function login_auth(){
        $dealer_loginname = Input::get('dealer_loginname');
        $dealer_password = Input::get('dealer_password');
        $dealer_hashed_pass = Hash::make($dealer_password);

    }
}
```

I Hash::make works fine in composer cmd
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqdYs.jpg and its also work on routes file

```
//Route::post('dealerpanel/login_auth','DealerController@login_auth');
Route::post('dealerpanel/login_auth',function (){
    $pass = Hash::make('abc');
    die($pass);
    //$2y$10$lSG0Dl3NCJ0ubWIwILzPk.SFGeLmwkw03v3NZ5yMgkg4fAry1Cjc2
});
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

seems like you didn't import `Hash` since your using namespaces.

try to add

```
use Hash;
```

on top of the `DealerController` file like,

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Hash;

    class DealerController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(){....
```

or just use

```
$pass = \Hash::make('abc');
```

Comment: Try bcrypt: like $pass = bcrypt($input['password']);